# How add and remove controls dynamically in javafx with scenebuilder

Tags: java

Please I need someone to show me How  to add and remove controls dynamically in javafx with scenebuilder or show me the link to a video pls

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do that. If you want to manipulate the scene graph dynamically you will have to do that in your Java code. You can start with a scene graph created by loading an FXML file created with Scenebuilder and then later manipulate that scene graph in your code.